# Decoding EC keys into Binary Format

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm trying to write a python function that will take a PEM formatted private key file and convert it into the raw binary representation, similar to what the following openssl function does:

```
openssl ec -in ec_private.pem -noout -text
read EC key
Private-Key: (256 bit)
priv:
    7a:f6:73:2f:58:1d:00:5a:fc:f2:16:f6:38:5f:f6:
    37:10:29:24:2c:c6:08:40:dd:7d:2a:7a:55:03:b7:
    d2:1c
pub:
    04:11:5b:3f:a3:9f:ae:41:b4:e3:2f:77:21:ca:72:
    f8:c1:78:14:83:64:7d:ab:d5:14:f0:8e:66:12:8b:
    d4:7f:ce:90:67:b9:0e:04:88:c9:c2:a9:f3:0f:5a:
    26:6a:07:84:1d:6c:07:74:13:ba:07:e7:45:69:b9:
    9d:4f:d3:ce:c6
ASN1 OID: prime256v1
NIST CURVE: P-256
```

But with the priv key formatted as a more code friendly format, like so

```
0x7A, 0xF6...
```

I've been trying to use the pyOpenSSL library, cryptography library, and PyNaCl libraries without any success.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to write a wrapper around the command line function that does this formatting for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, if anyone know the correct terminology for the "binary key" I'm trying to generate that would be super helpful. That's the best description I could come up with.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "raw binary format" I would call that a hex format.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing the wrapper around the openssl system library:

```
import os
def convert_key(keyfile):
    stream = os.popen('openssl ec -in {} -noout -text'.format(keyfile))
    output = stream.read().strip()
    keylines = output.splitlines()
    keystring = keylines[2].strip() + keylines[3].strip() + keylines[4].strip()

    formatted_key = "0x" + keystring.replace(":", ", 0x")
    return formatted_key
```

Which is a likely very brittle way to create the desired outcome, but I can't find a more pythonic way to do it.